# Default value of Combobox(form control) VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Hey I have been searching a lot on the internet but I haven't been able to find the solution. I have atleast 10-15 combobox(form control) in my workbook. I want them to display a default value of say "Select type". Now, I have tried doing this using the ".listindex" but then it doesn't allow me to change the value in the combobox(as the default is set permanently).

Can someone help? This is what I tried to use

```
With ws(1).shapes("Chill1").controlformat
 .listindex = 1
End with
```

Comment: .add item will just add an option "select type" in the combobox, which I already have done. Now I want the combobox to display that option("select type") as default when the person opens the workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default state of the Combobox would be blank, so if anything needs to be put in, it'll usually be an item from the list range.

e.g. the input range (from Properties) is

```
    A1:A10
```

and the cell link is

```
    B1
```

Then B1 can be manually or through a macro (workbook_open event) set to value: 1

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = 1
    End Sub
```

and A1 can contain the string 'Select Type'

That way everytime the workbook is opened, the macro sets the 1st values of each of these lists to "Select Type"

Comment: Yes you are right. I can put it in the workbook open event. Now, what I want is that if a person does choose some option among the list of items. That option should be saved, even if the person closes and opens the workbook again.

Comment: In that case, two changes need to be made

1. When the selection is changed by the user, another cell, say B2 should be set to some value, say '1' as a flag.

2. On workbook open, the code can check if cell B2 == 1. If so, it doesn't run the rest of the code.