# VBA Populate Combobox with text

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I know this is simple but have struggled to find a solution on Google or this site. I have a sub in workbook open that populates comboboxes with the .additem routine. This works find but actually what I want to do is tell it to display the text below so that my template looks neat when a user opens it.

How do I not only add the items but also get the combobox to display the desired text?

```
Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "Select Server"
Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "UK1-SQL-T002"
Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "UK1-SQL-T003"

Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Portfolio.AddItem "Select Portfolio"
```

So in this example I want the servers to be listed but want Select Server and Select Portfolio to be displayed on opening.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475537/default-value-of-comboboxform-control-vba?rq=1

Comment: A combo box will only show the listed items when you use it. Otherwise, you combo box will be "minimized" and show only the currently selected value. If you want to show all the items in the combo box (even when the combo box is not in use) then you should change to a ListBox.

Comment: Did you try adding code to the ThisWorkbook_Open or the Worksheet_Activate event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a specific item from Dropdown in excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232521/selecting-a-specific-item-from-dropdown-in-excel-vba)

Comment: did you not find `.value`?

Comment: Looking at the various comments it seems to me that everybody has a different understanding of what the question might be. Maybe the OP can provide some more descriptive details or (even better) a screenshot / mock-up of the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan_Sav commented, you are looking for the `.Value` of the Combo-Box:

So add the 2 lines below after your `AddItem` lines:

```
Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.Value = "Select Server"
Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Portfolio.Value = "Select Portfolio"
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, this is what I am after although apologies for missing a key point out on the original message. The Portfolio combobox has two columns associated to it and when I try this the box is blank?

Comment: @Carlos80 so what values (the second value) you want to display in `CB_Portfolio` ?

Comment: Ideally the Select Portfolio statement. This is a two column box because I want the user to select by name but the variable passed back to SQL is the ID number associated with the selection by name.